# SQL equivalent of the "relocate all files to folder" option?

Tags: sql-server

When restoring database using the GUI, there's an option "relocate all files to folder" which is very convenient.

I wonder if there's the same thing if I'm restoring db using T-sql? 
To me, finding out logical file names then put into the move clause seems to be too tedious and unnecessary.

Comment: It's tedious, sure, but how often are you restoring a database to a different server? Why isn't this automated (or why aren't your servers configured to have matching paths so this isn't an issue)?

Comment: Actually I just happen to need to restore a few dozen databases just once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no shortcut, no. The backup contains the original path to each and every file - a restore will try to put each file in its original location, unless you override it explicitly, and you have to do that for each file using `WITH MOVE`.